# How to remove TeX displayed equation markups from the output of Maxima tex?

Tags: maxima

How to remove all `$` signs from the output of, e.g., `tex(x^2-5*x+6);` ?

This question is more related to Maxima so I  post it here.

Comment: Removing the other extraneous material from the output: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20318328/1142217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tex1` instead of `tex`. This way the output won't be enclosed inside $$ delimiters. You can find more details on these matters in the [Maxima reference](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_9.html#Item_003a-tex1).

Answer (score 0):

Writing `set_tex_environment_default( "",  "" );` in your script would do the same.

From maxima manual

```
(%i1) get_tex_environment_default ();
(%o1)                       [$$, $$]
(%i2) tex (f(x) + g(x));
$$g\left(x\right)+f\left(x\right)$$
(%o2)                         false
(%i3) set_tex_environment_default ("\\begin{equation}
", "
\\end{equation}");
(%o3) [\begin{equation}
, 
\end{equation}]
(%i4) tex (f(x) + g(x));
\begin{equation}
g\left(x\right)+f\left(x\right)
\end{equation}
(%o4)                         false
```